# How to show load bar in ipad app while data is fetching from xml after default png is shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am fetching XML data  from server i want that when data is loading in progress i show a loading bar with default screen this is code in appDidFinishing

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    RootViewController * rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];    
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];  
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];  


    self.activityIndicator =  [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 67, 100, 100)];    

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];  
    [self.window addSubview:self.activityIndicator];  
    [self loadXMlTwo];
    [self loadXMlMain];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadXMlOne) withObject:nil];  

    [self.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];



    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
```

}

-(void)loadXMlMain{

```
NSURL*url= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://46.137.28.14/app/ipadApplic/working.xml"];



NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

//Initialize the delegate.

XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate

[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];         
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)

    NSLog(@"No Errors");

else

    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

}
-(void)loadXMlOne{

```
NSURL*url1=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://46.137.28.14/app/ipadApplic/rowone.xml"];






NSXMLParser *xmlParserRow = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1];

//Initialize the delegate.

RowOneParser *parser1 = [[RowOneParser alloc] initXMLParser];   
//Set delegate

[xmlParserRow setDelegate:parser1];         
BOOL success1 = [xmlParserRow parse];

if(success1)

    NSLog(@"No Errors");

else

    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

}
-(void)loadXMlTwo{
    NSURL*urlRowTwo=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://46.137.28.14/app/ipadApplic/rowtwo.xml"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParserRowTwo = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlRowTwo];

```
//Initialize the delegate.

RowTwoParser *parserRowTwo = [[RowTwoParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate

[xmlParserRowTwo setDelegate:parserRowTwo];         
BOOL successRow = [xmlParserRowTwo parse];

if(successRow)

    NSLog(@"No Errors");

else

    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is unblock your main thread while you are doing background fetch of xml data. Easiest way to do that is add your fetch operations in [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). Set up delegates for the class which fetches the xml and handle the response.

Comment: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/

Comment: mean instead  of USING XML Parsing i may use this

Comment: You still need to parse your xml data, but while you are fetching in the background you can unblock the uithread and display a activity indicator.

Comment: i am not getting that unblock uithread  and display indicator

Comment: Since you are fetching 3 xml files you need to do that in background and to display a progress bar you can use activity indicator.

Comment: thanks i am fetching xml in view did load so i am writing code in appDid Load which i have edited as you said its not working

Comment: What you are doing is blocking the uithread. Hence you are not able to show the progress bar. Read the links i have pasted and then try to design such that the xml fetching is done in background i.e another thread.

Comment: I have pasted all the code as you are saying may i call the xml in another thread i have seen a example in which its fetching in another thread and showing on MainThread the data